# Stabilization of hydrogen peroxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

It was given in a chemistry book that things like orthophosporic acid, acetanilide and sodium stannate stabilize hydrogen peroxide, while carbon, $\ce{MnO2}$ and $\ce{Pt}$ help decomposing it.
Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the explanation is that orthophosphate forms complexes -or even precipitate, traces of heavy metal ions present in the solutions. Many of these ions, like manganese and platin, will act as catalysts for the degradation of hydrogenperoxide. The phosphonic acid HEDP (Etidronic acid) is another example of a stabilizer.

Comment: Can u give complete equations for all of what u mentioned ?

Comment: I´d rather not. The chemistry of complexes in not my specialty so my answers would probabely either be wrong or to general to be of any use.